# gauge widget in odoo11 is not showing proper value

Tags: xml, python-3.x, odoo-11

I have created a gauge widget in odoo11 which shows the total Amount of money for which sales person had sold article, but the value inside the gauge is not showing value correctly. It is showing like this- **3,4.8k**. I want to make it show like this-**34807.5** or **34.8K**. The value which is shown in .xml file is a model field being called from .py file

I tried doing changes in the .py file(models) making float field to integer.

My model file(.py) -

class PosSession(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'pos.session'

```
def seetion_total(self):
    for rec in self:
        order_id = self.env['pos.order'].search([('session_id', 
                       '=', rec.name)])
        if order_id:
            rec.number_of_order = len(order_id)
            cancel = 0
            done = 0
            for order in order_id:
                for each in order.lines:
                    rec.subtotal_session += 
                           each.price_subtotal_incl
                    rec.untaxamount_total += each.price_subtotal
                    if each.discount:
                        rec.total_discount += (each.price_unit * 
                             each.qty) - each.price_subtotal
                    rec.sale_qty += each.qty
                rec.tax_amount += order.amount_tax
                if order.state == 'cancel':
                    cancel += 1
                if order.state == 'done' or order.state == 
     'invoiced':
                    done += 1
            rec.total_cancel_order = cancel
            rec.total_done_order = done
            if order.session_id.state == 'closed':
                rec.number_of_order = 0
                rec.total_discount = 0.0
                rec.sale_qty = 0
                rec.total_done_order = 0
                rec.total_cancel_order = 0
                rec.subtotal_session = 0
                rec.untaxamount_total = 0
                rec.tax_amount = 0

untaxamount_total = fields.Float('Total', 
                    compute='seetion_total',digits=(16,2))
tax_amount = fields.Float('Total Tax', 
                  compute='seetion_total',digits=(16,2))
subtotal_session = fields.Float('Subtotal', 
                       compute='seetion_total',digits=(20,5)
```

my view file (.xml) -

```
   <div class="oe_kanban_global_click" >
                                     <table style="height: 
     16px;margin-top: 10px;" width="100%">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td style="width:33%;text-align:center;">
 <field name="untaxamount_total" widget="gauge" 
       style="width:50px;height:90px;cursor:pointer;margin- 
          left:8px;undefined;position:relative; display:inline- 
                       block;width:66%"
    options="{'max_field': 'subtotal_session'}">Subtotal w/o 
                                         Tax</field>
</td>
<td style="width:33%;text-align:center;">
<field name="tax_amount" widget="gauge" 
        style="width:50px;height:90px;cursor:pointer;" 
        options="{'max_field': 'subtotal_session'}">Total</field>
        </td>
<td style="width:33%;text-align:center;">
<field name="subtotal_session" widget="gauge" 
            style="width:50px;height:90px;cursor:pointer;"
    options="{'max_field': 'subtotal_session'}">Subtotal</field>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
</div>
```